# Type mismatch expecting bool list but get int list

Tags: f#

I am going filter an `int list` based on the 2 boundaries. To do it i used the `List.filter` in this way:

```
let CountFilesInRange ele lowerRang upperRange=  
   match ele with
   | ele when lowerRang< ele< upperRange -> true 
   | _                                   ->false



List.filter (CountFilesInRange  0 5000) listOfSizes
```

In the last line I have this error with `listOfSizes`:

```
Type mismatch expecting bool list but get int list
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: `lowerRang< ele< upperRange` is not valid syntax; try `lowerRang < ele && ele < upperRange`.

Comment: @ildjarn - It looks like it might be valid since the error is in `filter` however it's probably parsed `(lowerRang < ele) < upperRange` so `upperRange` is inferred to be a `bool` and `CountFilesInRange 0 5000` has type `bool -> bool`.

Comment: it is ok right now, but it always gives me an empty list

Comment: Note that all the `match with` expression is useless as the "range check" `lower < ele && ele < upper` is already a boolean expression you can simply return it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As say @ildjarn  - not valid syntax
2. You have wrong order of parameters.
   Probably, you wanted to do this:

Example:

```
let listOfSizes = [1;2;3;4]

let betweenExclusive lowerBound upperBound value =  
   match value with
   | value when lowerBound < value && value < upperBound -> true 
   | _                                                   -> false

List.filter (betweenExclusive 1 4) listOfSizes |> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
[2; 3]
```

Link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/3179jr

**Edit:**

Thank you @Sehnsucht for the comment. This function can be rewritten as:

```
let betweenExclusive lowerBound upperBound value =  
   lowerBound < value && value < upperBound
```